# How to sort a dictionary in Swift based on Keys and Values

Tags: swift

I was trying to sort a Dictionary in Swift. The Dictionary I have is:

```
[
“Rhode Island": [
   "Providence",
   "Warwick",
   "Cranston"
  ],
"Mississippi": [
   "Jackson",
   "Gulfport",
   "Southaven"
  ],
"South Dakota": [
   "Sioux Falls",
   "Rapid City"
  ]
]
```

This is a Dictionary containing **Keys** as ***States*** and **Values** as ***Cities*** of United States. Is there any way I can sort this dictionary such that I can show the States and Cities in the alphabetical order in a UIPickerView which looks like the following:

```
[
"Mississippi": [
   "Gulfport",
   "Jackson",
   "Southaven"
  ],
“Rhode Island": [
   "Cranston",
   "Providence",
   "Warwick"
  ],
"South Dakota": [
   "Rapid City",
   "Sioux Falls"
  ]
]
```

Comment: When you say "show" what do you mean?

Comment: I was trying to present the States and cities in a UIPickerView

Answer (score 2):

**A dictionary is unordered by definition** and cannot be sorted.

Map the dictionary to an array of a custom type `State` with properties `name` and `cities`.

```
struct State {
    let name: String
    let cities: [String]
}

let dictionary = [
    "Rhode Island": ["Providence","Warwick","Cranston"],
    "Mississippi": ["Jackson","Gulfport","Southaven"],
    "South Dakota": ["Sioux Falls","Rapid City"]
]

let states = dictionary
    .map{State(name: $0.key, cities: $0.value.sorted())}
    .sorted{$0.name < $1.name}

print(states)
```

The `map` line converts the dictionary to `State` instances and sorts the cities. The `sorted` line sorts the states by name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn this into a sorted array, Sort the keys array and use the sorted keys array to choose the key/value pair at your index. Then when displaying the values sort them before displaying them.

```
var keys = dict.keys
keys.sort()
```

Then for your UIPicker at row i use dict[keys[i]].sorted()